# Table column width within a block

Tags: css, width, css-tables

I've coded this HTML snippet:

```
table{ 
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    display:block;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 150px; 
}
```

but it does not display the way I want it to. In fact, the width of the columns are not fixed but they depend on the size of the content that's added to the cell. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean? The width certainly seem fixed in this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nT85g/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this constraint ?

```
word-wrap
```

Check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If you set the width to 150px like you done before, it works ure ok?

Comment: The issue is with the "display:block". If I remove it, column's widths are just fine. If I enable it (and I need to in order for the scrollbar to display correctly), column's widths are wrong. Can anybody explain me why?